# How to add a fadeIn() hide-to-show effect without edit css

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery code :

```
$('.tracklistOff').find('.trackon').clone().insertAfter(($(param).parents('.trackon')));
```

When I insert that `$('.tracklistOff').find('.trackon').clone()` I'd like to apply an effect to it, like fadeIn() hide-to-show.

Tried `$('.tracklistOff').find('.trackon').clone().fadeIn()` but it go to show-hide-to-show, and that I want is just hide-to-show, without edit CSS adding `display:none;`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.tracklistOff').find('.trackon').clone().insertAfter(($(param).parents('.trackon')).hide().fadeIn();
```

Separated to make it more readable..

```
$('.tracklistOff')
.find('.trackon')
.clone()
.insertAfter(($(param).parents('.trackon'))
.hide()
.fadeIn();
```

Comment: Nice one, it works! P.S. And setting a time? like "in 2 seconds"? `.hide().fadeIn('2000')` seems to fail...

Comment: .hide().delay(2000).fadeIn();

Comment: fadeIn(2000) means it will fade immediately over a period of 2 seconds, not start fading after a delay of 2 seconds.

Comment: That's really strange now is that, if I put `fadeIn(2000);`, I can avoid `hide()`; its strange, isnt it?

Answer (score 2):

Clone it, then hide the clone, then insert it, then fade it in

```
$('.tracklistOff').find('.trackon').clone().hide().insertAfter(($(param).parents('.trackon')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `$('.tracklistOff').find('.trackon').clone().hide().fadeIn()`?